# Android: How to determine if an HTTP PUT request has finished processing

Tags: java, android, http-put

Just wondering if anyone knows how to determine when a HTTP PUT request is complete. For eg:

```
    HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPut putmethod = new HttpPut("http://abc.com/SETTINGS.TXT");
    putmethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
    HttpResponse response = http.execute(putmethod);
```

How can I tell when the file has completely transferred/written. Do I need to monitor the HttpResponse? If so, what I am looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your request is successfully complete then http client will return the success code 200 if it fails then it returns the another code (401 page not fount etc).

so you can check the code with the response and log appropriate message .

### Example

```
HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut putmethod = new HttpPut("http://abc.com/SETTINGS.TXT");
putmethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(data));
HttpResponse response = http.execute(putmethod);

if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()  == 200) 
            {
                is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                int ch;
                sb = new StringBuffer();
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) ch);
                }
                // Log sb . it prints the response you get.
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag, In my case the response code turned out to be 201 but thats not a biggie. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

if you want check that file has completely transferred then try this..

```
String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println("Data in .."+data);
```

in data you will get response from server...